# Organic groups access to /og

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, organic-groups

How do you limit access to the `/og` page to only authenticated users? I don't see to see an option under `/admin/user/permissions`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enabled the Organic Group Access module that comes with Organic Group, it will enable a checkbox inside Organic Group called "public", that if NOT checked will only give access to people that are part of a group. Does it help ?